# Dealing with over smart colleague

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, unprofessional-behavior, new-hires

I work with a person who is as same position as me but is 30 years older. I saw him being fancy with other colleagues on his second day.

He somehow knows less but talks more. He has been acting smart and asked me what I learned today that I didn't know yesterday. This would be fine coming from an old mate but I m a new person. Even I didn't get so cheeky with my colleague so fast.

How do I deal with people like this so they know to stay professional and that I am not that approachable or quick to open up?

While a part of induction included what I would be telling him, he pointed out to me something like he knew more than me, but of course he didn't.

Comment: What does being fancy with a colleague even mean?

Comment: It sounds like this guy was patronizing to you. Here is the definition of patronizing 1. treat with an apparent kindness that betrays a feeling of superiority. "“She's a good-hearted girl,” he said in a patronizing voice" synonyms: treat condescendingly, condescend to, look down on, talk down to, put down, treat like a child, treat with disdain

Comment: So the next time he approaches you trying to be helpful, but in a patronizing matter. Ask him politely not to patronize you. Often times, giving a name to this kind of behavior is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Give it sometime. When we are quick to judge other people, more often than not, our estimation is usually incorrect and we come to regret doing anything harsh. As you spend more time together, you will come to mutually respect each other.